# Compare cell values of a values in a row and update empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

In an excel table how can i compare cell in columns of a row. If a cell in column is empty then update cell with the value from the other cell.

Comment: What have you tried, and what happened when you tried it?  Questions with code (even if not working) get the best response here.

Comment: There is likely also an excel formula solution. Perhaps post to https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel

Answer (score 0):

With Vba like that

```
Sub PullBlanks()
    Dim StartRow As Long, LastRow As Long, GoodColumnName As String, CompareColumnName As String
    Dim Col1 As Long, Col2 As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsName As String
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    ' Properties, change that
    GoodColumnName = "A"
    CompareColumnName = "B"
    StartRow = 2
    wsName = "Sheet1"
    '# End Properties

    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
        Col1 = Range(GoodColumnName & 1).Column
        Col2 = Range(CompareColumnName & 1).Column
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, GoodColumnName).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = StartRow To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, Col2).Value <> "" Then
            ws.Cells(i, Col2 + 1).Value = "Good"
        Else
            ws.Cells(i, Col2).Value = ws.Cells(i, Col1).Value ' Value from GoodColumn
            ws.Cells(i, Col2 + 1).Value = "Changed"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

With formulas you must use additional column, when delete bad column.